# How to scroll data in LED dot matrix through multiple modules?

Tags: led, c, avr, data

I've been struggling in this issue for a long time, I know there are people who have done it.

But, I don't have much experience in C to have the skills to design or develop such complicated functions.

I want to scroll data, e.g. text, chars or numbers just like the nice projects in YouTube about the dot matrix.

Like this one: [How to Make a SCROLLING TEXT Display at Home](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e_pY-uGkDFA&t=17s)

I know how to display a char, but I don't know how to scroll it. If I try I don't get the results I want.

This is my function for displaying chars:

```
void draw(void)
{
  s=0;
  uint8_t data_shift_buf;
  for (l=0;l<26;l++)            // to print 26 letters
  {
    for (row=1;row<9;row++)     // for 8 matrix rows
    {

        SPI_TX_m16(data = (row<<8) | (Alphabet[s]),4);// trying set data by column
        s++;_delay_ms(300);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what does this mean ? `LED dot matrix throw multiple modules` ... what are you throwing?

Comment: It's obviously "through". Feel free to improve the question, as I just did.

Comment: What module do you have exactly? Maybe this will help: http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11516

Comment: @NickGammon Thanks for the edit :) Like, this one: http://www.belajarduino.com/2016/08/4in1-dot-matrix-led-module-32x8-pixel.html

Comment: Yep, the MAX7219 - you can scroll with that. See the link above. I don't know how to make an answer without copy/pasting the whole link. :)

Comment: @NickGammon Thank you so much, I've looked into the link and found a lot of development with the MAX7219, and found an interesting comment at the end of the posts: "There is also a demo of scrolling text, however that scrolls a chip at a time, not a pixel at a time. 
", which is what I'm looking for! I'm looking for scrolling by pixel.

Comment: The very next paragraph under that says: *Library updated on 2nd October 2015 to have smooth scrolling. A new example has been added which demonstrates this. To achieve this each for each display module (8 x 8 pixels) the code calculates the pixels for the byte before, the current byte, and the byte after. Then it applies the pixel offset to choose a starting point somewhere in those 24 (horizontally) pixels.*

Comment: WOW that should be amazing, really I'm trying to solve this problem for days. Yes, he calculation for the first and the second display, OK thank you so much for the support.

Comment: Take a look at the Parola.h library also.  https://github.com/MajicDesigns/MD_Parola  It can scroll up, down, left, right, and for large #s of displays.

Comment: Thank you for response, that library is very difficult for me, so I tried and tried until I did it on my own, I can only scroll to right. But the function is long compared to functions in Parola library it's written in C++, it's really interesting to do such things in small functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the function for my problem.

```
void draw(void)
{
uint32_t map_buffer=0;int8_t i,k;
uint8_t data_reg[4] = {0xaa,0xbb,0xff,0xff};      // random data to write
uint8_t dis_buf[4],no_device,no_col;s=0;l=3;

for (i=0;i<4;i++)
map_buffer |= data_reg[i] << i*8;                 // loading data into map_buffer

for (col=0;col<32;col++)                          // for 8 matrix columns
{
    map_buffer >>= 1;                            // start shifting the data by 1 pixel
    for (i=0;i<4;i++)
    dis_buf[i] = map_buffer >> i*8;              // loading shifted data into display buffers
    for (i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        for (row=1;row<9;row++)                 // for 8 matrix rows
        {
            SPI_TX_m(data = (row<<8) | (dis_buf[i]),i);
        }
    }_delay_ms(1000);
}
```

}